# Android OpenGLES Loading textures in GLThread then telling UI Thread to run a method

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am working on an application that uses OpenGL ES and I am trying to load textures in to memory before I start the application logic. I have tried a few solutions and have had no success.

My Activity Oncreate code.
My activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create a GLSurfaceView instance and set it
        // as the ContentView for this Activity.
        view = new GLSurfaceView(this);

        // Initiate the game renderer
        renderer = new AppRenderer(this);

        view.setRenderer(renderer);
        // Only render when we tell it to
        view.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);

        // Set the custom renderer as our view
        setContentView(view);

        startApplication();
    }
```

The above code works with bugs, I load the textures in my AppRenderers onsurfacechanged function. The problem is that startApplication() gets run before onsurfacechanged which causes textures that are bound when startapplication() has run, to not load and display white instead.

I do know that opengles does run on it's own thread.

So I tried to use an async task and a flag example below.

```
public class loadTextureTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        textureLoad = renderer.getTextureLoaded();
        while (textureLoad == false) {
            textureLoad = renderer.getTextureLoaded();
        }
        startApplication();
    }
}
```

after that I just replaced the "startApplication()" in the oncreate to initiating this async task so I can check when the textures have loaded.

```
    loadTextureTask = new loadTextureTask();
    loadTextureTask.execute((Void) null);
```

This has caused the following error "threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40de82a0)
" and takes a lot more time to load the textures with this method approximately 20x as long as it would load if this async task was not present..

What I am trying to accomplish is run the startApplication() method after the textures have loaded.

Note: My textures are all the power of 2.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! thank you in advance.

Comment: add `Thread.Sleep(100);` into while loop(bad solution but should help) ... better solution is: add listener(fx: `ITextureLoaddedListener` with `done` method) to renderer then in implementation of this listener in `done` method call `startApplication` and call method `done` of listener after program loads all textures(in place when you're setting _textureLoaded flag to true) ...

Comment: Hi Selvin thanks for the answer, can you elaborate on this method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it takes 20x times more since second thread calls renderer.getTextureLoaded(); again and again and this use a lot of CPU... so you can do this like:

Create interface:

```
interface ITextureLoaddedListener {
    void done();
}
```

in `AppRenderer` add (`variant I.`):

```
ITextureLoaddedListener _listener = null;
public void setTextureLoaddedListener(ITextureLoaddedListener listener) {
    _listener = listener;
}
```

or (`variant II.`) in `AppRenderer` constructor add

```
public AppRenderer(Context ctx, ITextureLoaddedListener listener){
    _listener = listener;
    //rest of old code
    LoadTexturesAsync(); 
}
```

for both version add:

```
public void LoadTexturesAsync() {
    new AsyncTask<Void,Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
        {
            //do your loading texture stuff here
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            if(_listener!=null){
                _listener.done();
            }
        }

    }.execute();
}
```

then let your `Activity` impements `ITextureLoaddedListener` and implementation should looks like:

```
public YourActivity extends Activity implments ITextureLoaddedListener{
    //....
    //rest of YourActivity code
    //....

    @Override
    protected void done()
    {
        startApplication();
    }
}
```

next add code to `onCreate` of `Activity`:

```
renderer = new AppRenderer(this); //or (for II.) renderer = new AppRenderer(this, this); 
renderer.setTextureLoaddedListener(this); //(for I.) no need for this if you choose II. variant
renderer.LoadTexturesAsync();//(for I.) no need for this if you choose II. variant
view.setRenderer(renderer);
```

for `I. variant` you should not call LoadTexturesAsync in constructor of`AppRenderer` since at this place you didn't set listener, yet.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply Selvin, the actual image loading code is done in onsurfacechanged as it loads texture into memory and that has access to the gl object the async task does not have access to the gl object so it can not load images in to gl.